# Change Active tab in navbar when router.navigate is used

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I'm using Angular 2 with Bootstrap 4. I can get the active tab to change using the following code:

**navbar.component.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
    &#9776;
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['']">My App</a>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:
true}">
        <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['']">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">
        <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/about']">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">
        <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/example']">Example</a>
      </li>      
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The line:

```
[routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"
```

works well at changing to the currently active tab, but when I navigate to a component using something like:

```
this.router.navigate(['']);
```

The active tab doesn't change. Is there a way to change the active tab when navigating like above?

Comment: its should be `routerLinkActive="active"` not `[routerLinkActive]="['active']"`

Comment: both are valid.

Comment: Something strange is going on because I was unable to reproduce the problem. I called this.router.navigate and it is correctly changing the class for me. Is this the latest version of the Angular router?

Comment: could you recreate that in a plunker?

Comment: I have similar problem. Check this [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/cwXf7NcVUdoNbipK1zD7/) forked from the official angular example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically you want to make your high-lighting in a service and call that service to apply your style when your URL equals a specific state. this is done by using

`this.router.url === '/myroute'`

here is my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6WFsnxv3jDsxcuc3AFYB?p=preview). NOTE that the active tab will change whether you use the links or the buttons. The buttons are what use the `this.router.navigate(['']);` like you asked in the question